# Google calendar V3 and Command line applications

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I am trying to develop a simple python application that does not use a webserver / appserver etc., and its a plain vanilla CLI app.

From what I have been reading on the Google Calendar client API V3, there is really no way to authenticate a CLI app without using a browser thanks to OAuth 2.0.

I am  building an application that I want to ideally run in the background and making updates to my calendar.  How do I do that when a browser intervention is required for authentication ?  Have I understood it wrong?  Please help.

PS : V2 of the API has the webservice to end point ClientLogin that seems to do this but I really want to use the latest API if I can.

Comment: I think you can use a browser once when you set it up, and then store the oauth token, if that makes it any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you follow an example here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate, you will have to authenticate only once with a browser, after you will find a 'calendat.dat' (or whatever name you choose) file, which will contain oauth token information and going to be used in further communications.

Comment: Yes I have tried this sample in python on linux.  The first time it opens the lynx browser (which is what I had installed) - is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: If you set "FLAGS.auth_local_webserver = False", that will give you a link, and won't open browser automatically, but I don't think it is possible to avoid browser interaction completely.